# Find the definition of PHP Constant

Tags: php, constants

I wish to know where (as in which php file) is a constant being defined. Do you know of any trick of getting this done fast?

Let's say that I'm not familiar with the whole system, but will need a quick fix on this constant. Browsing through each includes files is boring.

**UPDATE**
I'm using notepad++ and accessing the files through FTP client (FileZilla).

Comment: I am sure your favorite IDE has "search in folder" option .. so just look for the constant in the source code of all files in the folder

Comment: hmm, I access the files through FTP client. Let me see if it can search entire FTP site.

Comment: Ouch.. I think it's better to download all the files and work on them locally. Also, you should consider using a source control system like git or Subversion.

Comment: @Emil yeah.. planning to make a development server soon... thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

I usually just `grep` my way into Mordor:

```
grep -l 'define..CONSTANT' *
```

(Note: I always run Unix-like operating systems. I don't know about Windows, but most editors should support something similar).

Answer (score 2):

use a mult-file search tool or an IDE with that feature, and search across the project directory for `define('MY_CONST_NAME',` where `MY_CONST_NAME` is the name of the constant you want to find.

Answer (score 2):

You need [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home). Well, really you need a proper IDE, but as a quick fix: download all PHP files and do a search for files containing text `define AND CONSTANT`. The built in search program on Windows is terrible, so use Agent Ransack instead.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE you are using? If you are using Eclipse, then its quite easy.. just press `Ctrl` and click on the constant, it will take you to the line where this constant is defined..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend TextMate if your (hopefully) on a mac, if not, get Sublime 2 (beta).

Answer (score -2):

I don't know well what u want, but with `define("CONST_NAME", "value")` u define a const.

to check, you use this:

```
if(defined("CONST_NAME", "value")) { 
//const defined
} else {
//do anything
}
```